# How to execute a bat file in ASP.NET C# and trace into it

Tags: c#, asp.net, shell, process, system.diagnostics

I need to execute a bat file which calls a third party procedure, but firstable I tried to execute a simple bat which writes the output into a text file.
The text file is not created and I am not able to trace throught it with breakpoints, can you help me?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process si = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
si.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\";
si.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
si.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
si.StartInfo.Arguments = Server.MapPath("Temp/test.bat");
si.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
si.Start();
//string output = si.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
si.Close();
```

This is the content for the bat file:

```
echo test > test.txt
```

Comment: Make sure your using a path the IIS app pool user has write permissions on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed the manner, I just needed to change the path:

```
                    string path = Server.MapPath("Temp");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
                    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = PCombine(path, "test.bat");
                    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1}", PCombine(path, filename), PCombine(path, "new_" + filename));
                    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    proc.Start();
                    proc.WaitForExit();
                    proc.Close();
                    proc.Dispose();
```